# Solving the recurrence equation T(n) = 3 + m * T(n - m)

Tags: recursion, computer-science

I have a Computer Science Midterm tomorrow and I need help determining the complexity of a particular recursive function as below, which is much complicated than the stuffs I've already worked on: it has two variables

T(n) = 3 + mT(n-m)

In simpler cases where m is a constant, the formula can be easily obtained by writing unpacking the relation; however, in this case, unpacking doesn't make the life easier as follows (let's say T(0) = c):

T(n) = 3 + mT(n-m)

T(n-1) = 3 + mT(n-m-1)

T(n-2) = 3 + mT(n-m-2)

...

Obviously, there's no straightforward elimination according to these inequalities. So, I'm wondering whether or not I should use another technique for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about `m` - this is just a constant parameter. However you're unrolling your recursion incorrectly. Each step of unrolling involves three operations:

1. Taking value of T with argument value, which is `m` less
2. Multiplying it by `m`
3. Adding constant `3`

So, it will look like this:

```
T(n) = m * T(n - m) + 3 =                                        (Step 1)
     = m * (m * T(n - 2*m) + 3) + 3 =                            (Step 2)
     = m * (m * (m * T(n - 3*m) + 3) + 3) + 3 = ...              (Step 3)
```

and so on. Unrolling `T(n)` up to step `k` will be given by following formula:

```
T(n) = m^k * T(n - k*m) + 3 * (1 + m + m^2 + m^3 + ... + m^(k-1))
```

Now you set `n - k*m = 0` to use the initial condition `T(0)` and get:

```
k = n / m
```

Now you need to use a formula for the sum of geometric progression - and finally you'll get a closed formula for the `T(n)` (I'm leaving that final step to you).

Comment: @A.Loc - you wrote in your question `T(0)=c`, right? But it's not important, you just need to estimate a total number of steps